# What is SUSE's rationale for shipping Python 3.6 in Leap 15.4?

Tags: python, opensuse, qt, libreoffice

I recently switched from a Ubuntu 20.04 based distribution to openSUSE Leap 15.4.
While I feel more comfortable with some of SUSE's packaging decisions, certain others are confusing me.

As a Python developer, I have been working with Python 3.8 on Ubuntu and am surprised that openSUSE Leap 15.4, despite being a newer distribution, still ships with Python 3.6, which is already EOL (see [the schedule](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/)).

Having 3.6 as the default system Python causes some major problems:

- Using an EOL version of Python is a potential security risk. Even if SUSE have taken over development for the version they distribute, I suspect that maintenance will not be as active and well-supervised as if upstream were still providing support.
- Many Python packages have dropped support for Python 3.6, considering that it is EOL. Therefore, affected developers have to resort to installing a newer Python release such as 3.10 through the backports repository.
- This has numerous disadvantages, however. As many system-provided packages just target `#!/usr/bin/python3` or call `python3` via subprocess, you can't safely relink `python3` to `python3.10`.
- The set of repository packages for the newer Python is greatly reduced, meaning that it is less integrated with the system.

  - For instance, if you want to use the Python bindings of LibreOffice, it's not possible because they're tied to Python 3.6. This is particularly problematic if you need to use them in a larger application or toolkit that also comprises packages which depend on `Python >3.6`.
  - Similarly, you cannot use the system-provided PySide2/PyQt5 packages, so unless you are willing to build them from source, you have to install another copy of Qt instead of dynamically linking against the system's Qt. This is disadvantageous in terms of security, disk space and app style (as a third-party installation of Qt cannot properly access the system's themes).
  - In general, it is not elegant to install packages with binary extensions through PyPI when these could nicely link against system libraries instead.

All these points make me wonder why SUSE decided to ship Python 3.6 anyway? What is the rationale behind this decision?

What should I do now? Try to install all needed packages from source? Or, as a last resort, change distribution again?

Comment: FWIW, I switched to Fedora 37 a while ago. Much better in this regard. Has Python 3.11 with all relevant packages.

Comment: Update: Leap 15.5, which came out in early June, still relies on Python 3.6. There is a community repo, which offers 3.10, but unfortunately it comes without several necessary tools, including pip.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I suppose that nobody at SuSE is resopnsible for adding un up-to-date Python to the current distro. There was even a short note that the final Leap 15.5 would come with Python 3.10, but this proved to be a hoax.

Answer (score 4):

15.4 is the 4th update and relies on the sources to SLES. Therefore, since that is looking towards companies who do not like changes, they tend to stick with whatever version was initially released and only publish fixes.

SLES 15 was released with an old python version, therefore they will stick to that if they can until SLES 16 is release, probably not for another 2 years as there seems to be a 15.5 release on its way.

15.4 though does come with python 3.9 & 3.10, just maybe not all the sub-packages you need.

It's a commercial decision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I see that it is necessary to stick with the initial Python version on a commercial LTS distribution, I have to admit that I still don't fully understand their decision for Leap. Many backwards-incompatible changes have been made during the transition from 15.3 to 15.4. Then why not use 3.10 as the default Python, if it is already built for backports anyway?

Comment: @mara004 Probably because  it's too big a change.

Comment: Yes, but Leap 15.4 has included several big changes, like the removal of Python 2 and Qt4. How can switching from py36 to py310 be worse?

Comment: I use the anaconda python environment on leap 15.3 (not yet upgraded to 15.4).  That contains python 3.10 and runs as a user app.  I have not found any problems using this but I am more of a python user and code tinkerer rather than a developer.

Comment: P2 is still available but has been EOL'd for a while. Qt4 has been waving bye bye for years. P36 is not just dealing with what the distro supplies, but also what all those companies have developed against. It is seen as too big a risk.

Comment: @tckosvic As stated in the question, my main problem is that backported or foreign versions of python lack integration with the system's packages. In other words, I am tied to a Python version for which the distribution provides the packages I need (including pyuno, pyside2, and python-efl).

Comment: @Bib I see this may be SUSE's reasoning, but I disagree. Staying on py36 equally hinders any commercial users who would like to use reasonably state-of-the-art dependencies. To put it bluntly, if updating means to stay on EOL software anyway, then you don't need to update in the first place. Companies who are not even willing to rebuild a binary extension against py310 may be better advised not to update distro instead of hindering anyone else with their negligence.